# Nginx redirect all subdomains to main domain

Tags: redirect, nginx

I'm trying to redirect all subdomains to my main domain, but so far it isn't working. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
server {
    listen         [::]:80;
    server_name *.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
 listen [::]:443;
        server_name example.com;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example.com.key;

        #enables all versions of TLS, but not SSLv2 or 3 which are weak and now deprecated.
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

        #Disables all weak ciphers
        ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECD$

        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }
}
```

However, when I type e.g. `www.example.com` it redirects to `https://www.example.com`, how can I redirect all sub-domains to `https://example.com`?

Answer (score 12):

If you have multiple sites on same server and one of your main sites would be [www.example.com](http://www.example.com):

```
# main domain:

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ...
}
```

For all sub domains, bads or misspelled can be redirected to www:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.example.com;
    return 301 http://www.example.com;
}
```

Nginx will check first [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and if not matched all what ever other subdomains will be redirected to www one.

Comment: `fastcgi_script_name`?

Answer (score 5):

You can simply create a default server, that redirects everything to https://example.com like this:

```
server {
  listen      [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name localhost;

  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

All incoming requests, that don’t find a matching server will be served by the default server, which will redirect them to the correct domain.

Comment: but the same server can have several different domains and webpages, and the OP just asked to redirect everything from `*.example.com` to `example.com`